# click function triggered from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a button wrapped inside a div.
The problem is that if I click the button, somehow the click function is triggered from the div instead of the button.

Thats the function I have for the click event:

```
$('#ButtonDiv').on('click', '.Line1', function () {
    var myVariable = this.id;
}
```

Thats my HTML (after is is created dynamically!!):

```
<div id="ButtonDiv">
    <div class="Line1" id="Line1Software">
        <button class="Line1" id="Software">Test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So now myVariable from the click function is 'Line1Software' because the event is fired from the div instead of the button.

My click function hast to look like this because I am creating buttons dynamically.

**Edit:**

This is how I create my buttons and wrapp them inside the div

```
var c = $("<div class='Line1' id='Line1Software'</div>");
$("#ButtonDiv").append(c);

var r = $("<button class='waves-effect waves-light btn-large btnSearch Line1' id='Software' draggable='true'>Software</button>");
$("#Line1Software").append(r);
```

Comment: `#ButtonDiv` isn't the id of the button

Comment: I didn't say that it is? @spencer.sm

Comment: What element are you trying to get with `$('#ButtonDiv')` then?

Comment: @Anokrize the only way for **only** the `div` to fire the event is if you have used CSS to put the `button` behind the `div` (*or the `div` in-front*) or if you have `pointer-events:none` on the `buttton`. If you see my answer you will notice that i have replicated your code exactly and it works as you want it. So the problem must lie elsewhere.. Post an example that exhibits the actual problem because your posted code does not yet.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that neither the `div` nor the `button` have an `id`.

You code with the example html actually fires twice, once for each element since the event will bubble up and match both elements (since they are `.Line1`)

If you only want it to match the innermost element, then use `return false` to stop the bubbling.

```js
$('#ButtonDiv').on('click', '.Line1', function () {
    var myVariable = this.id;
    console.log(myVariable);
    
    return false;
});

var c = $("<div class='Line1' id='Line1Software'></div>");
$("#ButtonDiv").append(c);

var r = $("<button class='waves-effect waves-light btn-large btnSearch Line1' id='Software' draggable='true'>Software</button>");
$("#Line1Software").append(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ButtonDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Be carefull, they are added dynamically so only my div fires the event, not my button

Comment: @Anokrize no, you 1st your `button` fires the event and then the `div`. The `return false` will take care of this.

Comment: @Anokrize and in your original code it would not be `undefined` but `Line1Software`

Comment: Yes you are right it is Line1Software. I want to have Software though, which is the id of the button. And no it only fires once.

Comment: @Anokrize but the software has `.Line5` and not `.Line1` that you use as the selector in your `.on('click','.Line5', ..)`

Comment: Fixed it. This is only an example, I copied and pasted the wrong line.

Comment: @Anokrize it is very difficult to help when posting the wrong code :) Anyway, the original answer should work then. See the snippet which uses your current code and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You code with the example html actually fires twice, once for each element since the event will bubble up and match both elements (since they are .Line1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add an event listener to the button you should probably be using `$('#Software')` instead of `$('#ButtonDiv')`

Comment: There are multiple buttons and they are all in different div's. The "#ButtonDiv" is the main div where all other divs with the buttons are placed in.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit odd because you give yourself the answer... Look at your code, you are explicitly using **event delegation**:

```
$('#ButtonDiv').on('click', '.Line1', function () {
    var myVariable = this.id;
});
```

This code means that, for each click on a `.Line1` element, the event will be delegated to the `#ButtonDiv` element (thanks to **bubbling**).

If you do not want this behavior, just do that:

```
$('.Line1').on('click', function () {
    var myVariable = this.id;
});
```

This is also correct:

```
$('.Line1').click(function () {
    var myVariable = this.id;
});
```

Comment: I know that it should work like this but somehow it doesn't. Its fired from the div instead of the button... I don't know why though

Comment: You are aware that your button and your div share the same class, right?

Comment: I know but only the button should fire the event, not the div

Comment: As it is now only the div fires the event and the button doesn't fire anything

Comment: Well... I think you should be more explicit in your question because this is normally a trivial problem...